# Values for namespace in xmlns attribute

Tags: xml, namespaces

I see the below document using 2 namespaces

**

```
<root>
<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>
<f:table xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>
</root>
```

**

Question:-

Is there any naming convention for namespace or should it be only a valid http address?

For example:- In the below example I have given "test1" & "test2".Is it valid?

```
<root>
<h:table xmlns:h="http://test1.com">
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>
<f:table xmlns:f="http://test2.com">
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/), a "namespace name" **can be any valid URI** - that includes the HTTP URLs we are most familiar with, and other forms such as URNs (Uniform Resource Names), which are managed in different ways.

So in your example `http://test1.com` and `http://test2.com` are valid URIs, so they are valid namespace names.

However, this note (from [this section of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl)) clarifies how a URI *should* be chosen:

> The namespace name, to serve its intended purpose, SHOULD have the characteristics of uniqueness and persistence. It is not a goal that it be directly usable for retrieval of a schema (if any exists). Uniform Resource Names [RFC2141] is an example of a syntax that is designed with these goals in mind. However, it should be noted that ordinary URLs can be managed in such a way as to achieve these same goals.

The most obvious way of creating a URI which you can guarantee (to a reasonable degree) will be *unique* and *persistent* is to **use a domain which you own**. As long as you have authority over that domain, it is unlikely that someone else will choose the same URL to have a different meaning. Furthermore, anyone looking for an authority on that namespace will assume that you, as the controller of the domain, are that authority.

If you owned the domain `user1050619.com`, you could therefore use the namespace names `http://user1050619.com/XMLNS/Test1` and `http://user1050619.com/XMLNS/Test2`

It is not necessary for resolving that URL to result in anything useful (or anything at all), but **it is common practice to host some form of documentation there** - either a machine-readable document like a DTD or Schema Definition, or a human-readable page explaining the elements defined by that schema. Alternatively, you could redirect the user to a Rick Astley video ;)

Answer (score 0):

The namespace URI is not used by the parser to look up information.

I think it should be sufficient for the URIs for the h and f namespaces you mentioned to simply be unique, valid URIs.  In most examples, I've seen http used as the scheme name.

So, a perfectly valid namespace (that does not map to a valid website) could be:

```
xmlns:foo="http://my.example.ns"
```