# How do I call SOAP methods in PHP using namespaces (in params and methods) and nested structures (in params)?

Tags: php, soap

Assume I have this XML (it is a SOAP call)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ext="http://api.movilway.net/schema/extended">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ext:GetBalanceRequest>
      <ext:AuthenticationData>
        <ext:Username>Foo</ext:Username>
        <ext:Password>Bar$123!password</ext:Password>
        <ext:SessionID>as3hy4ri37g2f345</ext:SessionID>
      </ext:AuthenticationData>
      <ext:DeviceType>3</ext:DeviceType>
    </ext:GetBalanceRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

(Foo, Bar$123!password, as3hy4ri37g2f345 and 3 are just sample values)
Usually, when I want to do simple SOAP calls, I use a `SoapClient` like this:

```
$sc = new SoapClient('http://my.url/my/service?wsdl');
$result = $sc->someMethod(array('some' => 'params'));
```

But this one seems to use xsd namespaces and nested structures.

**Q**: How do I call methods with namespaces prefixes (ext:, in this case) AND parameters with namespaces prefixes (and nested structures)?

**Edit**: What I tried involves including the namespace as the uri option. And got an exception like this:

> SoapFault : Function ("GetBalanceRequest") is not a valid method for this service

The code I tried was this:

```
try {
    $client = new SoapClient('http://THEURLHERE/Path/To/The/Service?wsdl', array('uri' => 'http://api.movilway.net/schema/extended'));
    print_r($client->GetBalanceRequest(
        array(
            'AuthenticationData' => array(
                'Username' => 'MYUSERHERE',
                'Password' => 'MYPASSWORDHERE'
            ),
            'DeviceType' => 1
        )
    ));
} catch(Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Assume there's no error nor typo since I got the required XML directly from the documentation.

**Q+**: What must I add to the code to send such request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the correct term is not "extension", but "namespace" - it's just coincidence that the namespace here is called "extended" and has been given the alias `ext:` in the example.

Secondly, an XML namespace is simply a way of saying "these elements and attributes are of a particular type"; it does not automatically imply any special structure beyond normal XML - it has no automatic relationship to an XSD, for instance. A namespace is uniquely identified by a URI, which needn't actually point anywhere (see [this previous answer for more on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131367/values-for-namespace-in-xmlns-attribute/26131808#26131808)). Within a document, it is given an arbitrary prefix, so that you don't have to write the URI next to every element.

SOAP itself uses the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` for the elements that represent the SOAP "envelope", here given the alias `soapenv`. The "body" of the SOAP message is not in that namespace, so it is common for SOAP services to declare their elements as part of some other specific namespace; if they didn't, they would be in the default, nameless, namespace.

So, so much for theory. On to practice:

If you are using a WSDL to load the web service, and that WSDL is properly formed, the SOAPClient class should add the appropriate namespace to your request automatically. Since the request exists entirely inside that namespace, there is no need to distinguish between "`AuthenticationData` in namespace `http://api.movilway.net/schema/extended`" and just "`AuthenticationData`".

If this doesn't work for some reason, or you have no WSDL, you may need to [create `SoapVar` objects](http://php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php) with the appropriate namespace assigned to them.

However, based on the error message you just edited into your question, all of the above may be completely irrelevant, because the problem might have nothing to do with namespaces at all - you are operating in WSDL mode, and the client is telling you that the method doesn't exist. So, the obvious question to me is, is that method definitely defined in that WSDL file?

Comment: You're right. The documentation I received is wrong! I changed GetBalanceRequest to GetBalance -by inspecting the WSDL-